# How can I add child object to the parent generic type in c#

Tags: c#, generic-collections

In java I can do it with extends keyword in Generic Type but in C# I cannot figure out.

I have a 3 classes, one of them is the base class.

```
public class BaseEntity { 
    public string Id {get;set;} 
}

public class EntityA : BaseEntity {}

public class EntityB: BaseEntity {}
```

Then I have a mock class for dataset. With generic type, the minimum constraint is the `BaseEntity`

```
public class MockDataStore<T> : IDataStore<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    List<T> items = new List<T>();

    public async Task<bool> AddAsync(T item)
    {           
    }

    public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(T item)
    {           
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(T item)
    {           
    }
}
```

But when I want to add one of the child class to the `items` list, the compailer says this is not possible.

> Cannot convert From EntityA to T

```
items.Add(new EntityA());
```

I want to use the generic type, because of Add, Update and Delete methods.

Yes if I use the `List<BaseEntity> = new List<BaseEntity>()` then I will not get the **cannot convert** message. But in this case the Add, Update and Delete methods will be wrong.

However I have added `where T : BaseEntity` this constraints and grr.

What I want to achive is that the `T : BaseEntity` typed `items` list filled up with the child items of the `BaseEntity`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Where are you writing `items.Add(new EntityA());`? Inside `MockDataStore`? If so, why?

Comment: If you replace `where T : BaseEntity` with `where T : BaseEntity, new()`, you can `items.Add(new T());`.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Because I wanted a fast solution :).

Comment: If you want this datastore to be generic, then don't use `new EntityA()` inside that class. Instantiate it with `new MockDataStore<EntityA>()`, then in `AddAsync()`  use `items.Add(item)`.

Comment: Not show where it is failing makes it hard to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have two options here:

#### 1. Remove the unneeded generics.

I don't think you need generics here at the class level. You can just have a list of the base class and work with that:

```
public class MockDataStore
{
    List<BaseEntity> items = new List<BaseEntity>();

    public async Task<bool> AddAsync(BaseEntity item)
    {           
    }

    public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(BaseEntity item)
    {           
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(BaseEntity item)
    {           
    }
}
```

#### 2. Use generics through a proper inheritance chain.

This is probably not what you want, as you would end up with multiple classes, but I will leave it here just in case:

```
public abstract class MockDataStoreBase<T> : IDataStore<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    protected List<T> items = new List<T>();

    public virtual async Task<bool> AddAsync(T item)
    {           
    }

    public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(T item)
    {           
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(T item)
    {           
    }
}

public class EntityADataStore : MockDataStoreBase<EntityA>
{
    public override async Task<bool> AddAsync(EntityA item)
    {
        bool result = await base.AddAsync(item);
    }

    //...
}
```

Now, `EntityADataStore.items` will be a `List<EntityA>`.